# if vs short circuit evaluation in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am wondering what makes *if* faster than short-circuit evaluation in my code:

```
GC.disable
N = 5000

def x
    j = nil
    N.times {
        if j
            j << 'a'.freeze
        else
            j = ''
        end
    }
    j
end

def y
    j = nil
    N.times {
        j && j << 'a'.freeze || j = ''
    }
    j
end

t = Time.now
N.times { x }
p Time.now - t

sleep 0.1

t = Time.now
N.times { y }
p Time.now - t
```

No matter how many times I run the code under no extra CPU load, I get:

```
3.826009846
4.137173916
```

Or something close to that.

Same goes with integers, if slightly modify the code and make j = nil, and then 0, and then add + 1 to j.

What makes the method y slower than method x?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you on?  What kind of system?  I ran this on a 5 year old MBP with Ruby 2.6.4.  I ran it twice with 5000 and got `x: 0.575801, y: 0.232743 ` and `x: 0.571195, y: 0.243702`

Comment: Oh wow, I have tried Ruby 2.5 and 2.7 both on GNU/Linux. 2.5 on codeanywhere PaaS and 2.7 on my own system. x was always faster by 0.2+ to 0.3+ seconds on multiple runs...

Comment: I may have been mistaken about my initial comment.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED as per comment. Here's a way to improve the x method. B is your method, C is the improved version because with this syntax the right side of && never gets executed.  [Benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.1/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) is the standard Ruby way of doing exactly what the class is intended to be used for easy to read docs.  To see why `Time.now` is not recommended, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483168/3625433).  Also it's common to move the iteration to the Benchmark as to not clutter up your actual methods.

```
require 'benchmark'
GC.disable

N=50000

class Foo
  def a
    j = nil
    if j
        j << 'a'.freeze
    else
        j = 'not nil'
    end
    j
  end

  def b
    j = nil
    j && j << 'a'.freeze || j = 'not nil'
    j
  end

  def c
    j = nil
    j && (j << 'a' || j = 'j')
    j
  end
end
foo = Foo.new
foo.a
foo.b
foo.c
Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |x|
  x.report(:a) { N.times {foo.a }}
  puts "j is no longer nil, but it's a string #{foo.a} <- see"
  x.report(:b) { N.times {foo.b }}
  puts "j is equal to #{foo.b} which is a string, not nil"
  x.report(:c) { N.times {foo.c }}
  puts "look for j, nothing here *#{foo.c}* but emptiness"
end

puts "\n take 2\n"

Benchmark.bmbm(10) do |x|
  x.report(:c) { N.times {foo.c }}
  x.report(:a) { N.times {foo.a }}
  x.report(:b) { N.times {foo.b }}
end
```

Results:

```
j is no longer nil, but it's a string not nil <- see
j is equal to not nil which is a string, not nil
look for j, nothing here ** but emptiness
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
a            0.005619   0.001018   0.006637 (  0.007648)
b            0.005097   0.000924   0.006021 (  0.006847)
c            0.003488   0.000025   0.003513 (  0.003783)
------------------------------------- total: 0.016171sec

                 user     system      total        real
a            0.006934   0.000331   0.007265 (  0.010790)
b            0.004609   0.000086   0.004695 (  0.005038)
c            0.004939   0.000148   0.005087 (  0.009489)

 take 2
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------
c            0.004118   0.000097   0.004215 (  0.005652)
a            0.005844   0.000155   0.005999 (  0.017280)
b            0.005498   0.000161   0.005659 (  0.013625)
------------------------------------- total: 0.015873sec

                 user     system      total        real
c            0.006040   0.000133   0.006173 (  0.013035)
a            0.005715   0.000081   0.005796 (  0.006672)
b            0.004042   0.000016   0.004058 (  0.004220)
```

Comment: I think that's 'benchmark' with downcased b. Calling the `nil?` is a bit more overhead as well. Also, I used 2 loops in my test. The reason was j is assigned to new string 5000 times, then the `||` and `if` condition is in action 5000 times. And same goes in the method, the method utilizes `&&` once j is set. Also, here `j rescue nil` is never used. j is string always, and it's doing no operation, so there's no way j raises error... Also, I didn't use benchmark library because I don't actually know how it works. Time.now - t here shows the monotonic time + time required to call `Time.now`.

Comment: require works with `benchmark` or `Benchmark`.  For rest see updated answer.

Comment: `LoadError (cannot load such file -- Benchmark)`

Comment: try `require 'benchmark'` I updated my answer. Not sure why, but I tried with `Benchmark` on a remote linux server and got the error, but it works on my local Mac with `Benchmark`.